Externally link to a specific html document state (after clicking the image and the slider opens)
TLDR: How could you externally link to an image within a slider deck. Not just the image url, but the actual image in the slide deck where you could still arrow through to the other images.
The URL https://storage.neros.fr/Images/cybot_sonar_1.jpg only produces the image obviously and https://storage.neros.fr/Images/ only takes you to the index. Clicking the image from https://storage.neros.fr/Images/ does not change the URL.
The html document prior to image click has the overlay hidden and there are no image id's within the class.
<div id="pv-overlay" class="hidden">
        <div id="pv-container" class="" style="width: 405px; height: 1182px; left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>

The html document after the image click has the overlay shown, and the image id tag is added.
<div id="pv-overlay" class="">
        <div id="pv-container" class="" style="width: 405px; height: 1182px; left: 20px; top: 20px;">
                <img id="pv-content-img" src="/Images/cybot_sonar_1.jpg" style="left: 0px; top: 439px;"></div>

Is there a way to externally link to this html document status?
I have thought about linking by using a fragment URL like:
https://storage.neros.fr/Images/#pv-content-img

But the tag doesn't really exist until the image is clicked. Where would you add the tag and the source? I don't think this solution would work.
I assume this needs to be done somehow with some additional javascript to the h5ai code, perhaps adding a new link for redirects, catches and loading a html document with the appropriate start status based on the link clicked... A lot more work I'm hoping to avoid. Any ideas?

You can read the URL fragment when the page has loaded, and depending on the value, decide what to do.

The issue is that the part of the page that I want to fragment to, hasn't been loaded yet. It only loads onclick.

So you'll need to execute that same functionality that currently works on click, when the page loads then.
